# Do .tk domain names rank lower than premium tlds?

Tags: seo, dns, ranking

My observation is that google doesn't rank dot.tk domain names as highly as other premium tlds like .com .net .org etc.

Is this correct? Does anyone have evidence either way that google ranks dot.tk domains equal to or lower than premium tld's?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about explaining the business decisions of a company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.tk is a country code domain for Tokelau.  I imagine these are not ranked highly in other countries.  I believe they use it for localized search results - http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/021424.html

**EDIT** I stand corrected - ABerezovskiy's answer should be accepted since google treats it as a gTLD.

Comment: `.tk` is treated as gTLD by Google, not as ccTLD.

Answer (score 4):

While there is no special proof that .tk domains will rank lower, Google has a [KB page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922) explaining that most widely used ccTLDs will NOT be used for localization:

> Google treats some ccTLDs (such as .tv, .me, etc.) as gTLDs, as we've
>   found that users and webmasters frequently see these more generic than
>   country-targeted. Here is a list of those ccTLDs (note that this list
>   may change over time).
>
> .ad
>
> .as
>
> .bz
>
> .cc
>
> .cd
>
> .co
>
> .dj
>
> .fm
>
> .io
>
> .la
>
> .me
>
> .ms
>
> .nu
>
> .sc
>
> .sr
>
> .su
>
> .tv
>
> **.tk**
>
> .ws